# Create a constraint based on column value to ensure not null

Tags: sql, constants, psql

I have a table with 4 columns, let's say: `col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4`, where `col_1` is of type `TEXT` and the others are `INTEGER`.

I want to add a constraint on `col_1` that goes as follow:

```
if (col_1 = 'a') then col_2 cannot be NULL
if (col_1 = 'b') then col_2 AND col_3 cannot be NULL
if (col_1 = 'c') then col_4 cannot be NULL
```

I tried to use a `CHECK` as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE "my_table" 
    ADD CONSTRAINT check_for_type
        CHECK ((col_1 = 'a' AND 'col_2' IS NOT NULL)
               OR (col_1 = 'b' AND ('col_2' IS NOT NULL AND 'col_3' IS NOT NULL))
               OR (col_1 = 'c' AND 'col_4' IS NOT NULL)
              );
```

But it is still allowing me to add a row with `col_1 = 'a'` and `col_2 = NULL`

I'd be grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `'col_2' IS NOT NULL` will always be true. You probably mean `col_2 IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Yes! Thats right! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'col_2' IS NOT NULL
```

will always be true since it is comparing a hardcoded string of the text 'col_2' against null. It is not comparing the value in that column with null.

To refer to the value in the column, you will want to use double-quotes or no quotes.

What you are looking for is likely:

```
ALTER TABLE "my_table" ADD CONSTRAINT check_for_type
CHECK (
  (col_1 = 'a' AND col_2 IS NOT NULL)
  OR (col_1 = 'b' AND (col_2 IS NOT NULL AND col_3 IS NOT NULL))
  OR (col_1 = 'c' AND col_4 IS NOT NULL)
);
```

This is just your original constraint treating `col_2`/`col_3`/`col_4` as column names instead of hardcoded strings.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your problem, please accept it. Or, if it helped at all, please upvote.